# remove special character in a List or String

Tags: machine-learning, python, nltk, ipython

[image]

Input_String is Text_Corpus of Jane Austen Book

output Should be :
['to', 'be', 'or', 'not', 'to', 'be', 'that', 'is', 'the', 'question']

But getting this Output :
['to', '**be,**', 'or', 'not', 'to', '**be:**', '**that'**, 'is', 'the', '**question!**']

Comment: I don't know how to remove the special characters thats why I asked the question  here. u can execute & try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions can be used to create a simple tokenizer and normalizer:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
import re

def tokens(text: str) -> list(str):
    "List all the word tokens in a text."
    return re.findall('[\w]+', text.lower())

assert tokens("To be, or not to be, that is the question:") == ['to', 'be', 'or', 'not', 'to', 'be', 'that', 'is', 'the', 'question']
```

Otherwise, use an established library like [spaCy](https://spacy.io/api/token) to generate a list of tokens.

Comment: Man, u r very good programmer. Your program is 100%  correct. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by Regular Expresiions

```
import re
modified_string = re.sub(r'\W+', '', input_string) # on individual tokens 
modified_string = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9_\s]+', '', input_string) # on sentence itself.Here I have modified RegEx to include spaces as well
```

'\W == [^a-zA-Z0-9_], so everything except numbers,alphabets and _ would be replaced by space

Comment: Output according to ur code is :     'tobeornottobethatisthequestion'

Comment: Updated the answer to include spaces is RegEx

Comment: Still not working..  u can test ur code using any Input_string

Comment: It removes unnecessary characters from sentence. You need to do split() after this to get tokens

Comment: Thanks but Brian Spiering program is short & easy

Answer (score 0):

I would use regex. I can only say what would work for the input sentence I can deduce from your desired output:

```
s = 'to be, or not to be: that is the question!'
```

I simply remove all characters that are not letters (upper or lower case) or spaces.

```
import re

pattern = r'[^A-Za-z ]'
regex = re.compile(pattern)

result = regex.sub('', s).split(' ')

print(result)
```

> ['to', 'be', 'or', 'not', 'to', 'be', 'that', 'is', 'the', 'question']

---

### Edit

Based on the update comment from OP - my answer can be adjusted to work on each of the words via simple interation of the sentences:

```
cleaned_sentenced = []    # will become a list of lists

for sentence in sentences:
    temp = [regex.sub('', word) for word in sentence]
    cleaned_sentences.append(temp)
```

This uses `regex` as defined up above.

Comment: Not working with this List :-                                                                               ['alice', 'how', 'long', 'is', 'forever', 'white', 'rabbit', 'sometimes', 'just', 'one', 'second']

Comment: You need to specify in your question exactly what the **inputs** could be. My answer works for what you provided. Are you passing actual sentences (single strings) or are you giving the list of words? Please edit your question to include this information, do not edit my answer.

Comment: Input_String is Text_Corpus of Jane Austen Book then I convert this corpus into the List_of_Words then I execute

Comment: @Mano - see my edit.

Comment: Thanks . Your code is also correct but  Brian Spiering program is short & easy.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option for you, but it should be a bit more slow than the rest of the answers.

```
import string
s = 'to be, or not to be: that is the question!'
punct_set= set(string.punctuation)#Saving punctuation into a set
s = ''.join(ch for ch in s if ch not in punct_set)#Get every character and remove punct
```

Another way is to use the `translate` method. In python 3, a dictionary should be passed to the method. `None` maps the character that will be removed.

```
import string
s = 'to be, or not to be: that is the question!'
translation = dict.fromkeys(map(ord, string.punctuation), None)#Dictionary with punctuation to be removed
no_punct_s = s.translate(translation)
```

Comment: Thanks but Brian Spiering program is short & easy

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the python regular expression library `re`. It will look something like this:

```
import re

def text2word(text):
    '''Convert string of words to a list removing all special characters'''
    result = re.finall('[\w]+', text.lower())
    return result
```

If you can log the result on the console to see the output that the function returns

For example:

```
string = " To be or not to be: that is the question!"
print(text2word(string))
```

Ouput:
`['to', 'be', 'or', 'not', 'to', 'be', 'that', 'is', 'the', 'question']`